# Attempt at finding zeta zeros by recurrence of zeta function.

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, roots, riemann-zeta

The following Mathematica program converges to most of the riemann zeta zeros, by using an approximation as a starting point.

```
Clear[n, k, a]
Do[a = 1/2 + N[I*2*Pi*(n - 11/8)/LambertW[(n - 11/8)/Exp[1]], 100];
 Do[a = a - Im[Zeta[a]]*I;,
   {k, 1, 80}] 
  Print[a],
 {n, 1, 12}]
```

Where the key statement is the iteration of:

```
a = a - Im[Zeta[a]]*I
a = a - Im[Zeta[a]]*I
a = a - Im[Zeta[a]]*I
a = a - Im[Zeta[a]]*I
```

80 times.

The approximation is the one by Andre LeClair in a paper on arXiv.

Out comes the values of the zeta zeros, but it misses a few and doubles some due to the starting values in the LambertW approximation.

$$1/2+14.134725141734693790457251983562 I$$
$$1/2+21.022039638771554992628479593896902777334 I$$
$$1/2+25.0108575801456887632137909925628218186595499 I$$
$$1/2+30.42487612585951321031189753058409132018156002372 I$$

Is this accurate enough to approach to the Riemann hypothesis?

Comment: I'm afraid that, yes, it almost certainly is useless.  The first _ten trillion_ some-odd zeroes have been found and computed to reasonable accuracy, using various other schemes, and it's hard to see how _any_ approximation scheme could lead to reasonable progress on the conjecture itself.

Comment: It is still interesting that such a simple recursion leads to an accuracy of over 15 digits.    In subsequent work,  we derived an *exact* equation satisfied by the n-th zero that depends only on n.     You can solve it numerically with FindRoot,  to whatever accuracy you like.   We went up to thousands of digits.   I think this later formula is an important step toward the RH.

Comment: @AndréLeClair I used a word with a negative connotation regarding the approximation. It is still what experts would call a partial progress towards the Riemann Hypothesis, I agree.

Comment: I like your question...+1